# Ver diferencia de dias entre dos fechas en POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy intentando sacar la diferencia de dias entre dos fechas con esta funcion:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION otras(fecha_vcto date,fecha_emision date)
RETURNS int
AS 
$$
DECLARE
    diasfecha3 int;
BEGIN

            Select(timestamp fecha_emision-timestamp fecha_vcto) into diasfecha3;
            return diasfecha3;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Entonces no se si con esa forma no se puede utilizar variable. Ya que me da error al crear la funcion. Asi cambie los parametros por tipo timestamp aparece el mismo error. Alguien me podria decir que puedo hacer o que tengo mal.

Comment: Qué error marca?

Answer (score 1):

No se que fué el objetivo de colocar `timestamp` en el select

```
Select(timestamp fecha_emision*-timestamp fecha_vcto) into diasfecha3;
return diasfecha3;
```

Cambiado esa parte a mí me funcionó perfectamente el código.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION otras(fecha_vcto date,fecha_emision date)
    RETURNS int AS  $$
DECLARE
    diasfecha3 int;
BEGIN

    Select(fecha_emision-fecha_vcto) into diasfecha3;
    return diasfecha3;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Resultado:

```
select otras('21/11/2019', '20/10/2019')

otras
--------------
-32
```

Comment: No entendí, que cambiaste del código.

Comment: @JoanSebastianOviedo le quité el timestamp de la consulta select